# 10.11.1: LAB: Course Grade

Tags: python

> Write a program that reads the student information from a tab separated values (tsv) file. The program then creates a text file that records the course grades of the students. Each row of the tsv file contains the Last Name, First Name, Midterm1 score, Midterm2 score, and the Final score of a student. A sample of the student information is provided in StudentInfo.tsv. Assume the number of students is at least 1 and at most 20. Assume also the last names and first names do not contain whitespaces.
>
> The program performs the following tasks:
>
> Read the file name of the tsv file from the user.
>
> Open the tsv file and read the student information.
>
> Compute the average exam score of each student.
>
> Assign a letter grade to each student based on the average exam score in the following scale:
>
> ```
> A: 90 <= x
> B: 80 <= x < 90
> C: 70 <= x < 80
> D: 60 <= x < 70
> F: x < 60
> ```
>
> Compute the average of each exam.
>
> Output the last names, first names, exam scores, and letter grades of the students into a text file named report.txt. Output one student per row and separate the values with a tab character.
>
> Output the average of each exam, with two digits after the decimal point, at the end of report.txt. Hint: Use the format specification to set the precision of the output.

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
m1=int(data\[2\].strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```
filename=input("Enter the file name: ")
file =open(filename)
f = open('report.txt','w')


mid1=0
mid2=0
final1=0

count=0

for line in file:
count=count+1
data =(''.join(line.split())).split()
m1=int(data\[2\].strip())
m2=int(data\[3\].strip())
m3 = int(data\[3\].strip('\\n'))
mid1=mid1+m1
mid2=mid2+m2
final=final + m3
avg = (m1+m2+m3)/3.0
grade = 'F'
if avg\>=90:
grade='A'
elif(avg\>=80):
grade='B'
elif(avg\>=70):
grade='C'
elif(avg\>=60):
grade='D'
f.write(''.join(data)+""+ str(grade)+"\\n")
avg1=round(mid1/count,2)
avg2=round(mid2/count,2)
avg3=round(final/count,2)

    f.write("\nAverages: Mid1"+str(avg1)+",Mid2"+str(avg2)+", Final"+str(avg3))
    f.close
```

Comment: You can use the `csv` module to parse TSV files, and it's much more robust than `str.split()` for this purpose. Please include a sample of the file. Start debugging with `print(data)`. And ask an explicit question rather than burying an implied question in the post.

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. All the indentation is gone, and this is critical for Python. Also, since you didn't  post it into a code block the Stacks editor escaped some of the special characters. See [formatting code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are not allowed to use `csv` module.

https://onlinegdb.com/a40lEdMC1

```py
filename = 'scores.tsv' #input("Enter the file name: ")

grade_map = {'A': 90, 'B': 80, 'C': 70, 'D': 60, 'F': 0}
exams = {'Midterm1': [], 'Midterm2': [], 'Final': []}

with open(filename, 'r') as IN, open('report.txt', 'w') as OUT:
    for row in IN:
        ln, fn, *scores = row.strip().split('\t')
        scores = list(map(float, scores))
        exams['Midterm1'] += [scores[0]]
        exams['Midterm2'] += [scores[1]]
        exams['Final'] += [scores[2]]
        average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
        for letter in grade_map:
            if grade_map[letter] <= average:
                break
        row = '\t'.join((ln, fn, *map(str, scores), letter))
        print(row, file=OUT)

    
    print('', file=OUT)
    for exam in exams:
        average = sum(exams[exam]) / len(exams[exam])
        print(f'{exam:>8} average: {average:.2f}', file=OUT)
```